# iPhone 6 upgraded to iOS 10 and now Outlook calendar not syncing

Tags: data-synchronization, ms-office, calendar, iphone, ios

I have a Micosoft Outlook 2013 calendar account synched on my iPhone.  Since I upgraded the iPhone to iOS 10.0.1, the calendar is not upating.  I tried changing the calendar setting from push to fetch and back, and turning off the calendar in the account and re-adding it and neither worked.  Email for the same account is updating routinely with no issues.  It has been nearly 2 days, and because turning the calendar account temporarily off wiped the old data and it has not synched since I turned it back on again, I have nothing.  Please help me!

Comment: I'm using iOS 10.0.1 on an iPhone 6 and iPad Air 2, both have Outlook.  My email and calendar are syncing without a problem.

Comment: Same problem here. Also iPhone 6. iOS 10.0.2 is out, but no change. Also no change after re-installing itunes on my laptop (Windows 19). Synchronization seems to be running as it should be ("synchronizing calendar" is shown on status line) but no calendar items are copied. Can't seem to find specific information on this from Apple.

Comment: Window 10 that is

Comment: @CLR have you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a minor iOS bug preventing iPhone from working with Outlook data. I think the best way is to wait for a week or two till Apple will fix the problem in one of the upcoming updates.

If you need to solve this issue asap, try Akruto: http://www.akruto.com/sync-iphone-with-outlook/

It works like an Exchange server, so if that wouldn't work that means Apple messed up with Exchange ActiveSync technology in iOS 10.0.1 and you still need to wait for a new iOS release.

Answer (score 0):

We are receiving reports of spontaneous deletion from calendars delegated to a mix of iOS 9.3.5 13G36 and iOS 10.0.1 14A403 devices. Looking for reproducible occurrences with data to report to MS or Apple.

Comment: When you say "Looking for reproducible occurrences," do you mean you cannot investigate until additional people report the same problem?  Or is there additional information you need to investigate my situation further?